# Is it possible to recover git files not pushed?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-pull, recover

I ran into a terrible situation where I updated my local copy 2 and I forgot that I had built upon my local copy one, therefore when I tried to pulled the local copy 1 it returned some error and to get rid of that I guess I stashed the valuable changes on that copy. I'm not sure if I had commited (definitely no pushed) my local copy 1. 
After pulling to this copy and of course stashing the previous change I realized that I lost a lot of things.
Is there away I can recover the nonpushed data?

Answer (score 1):

If the code was actually committed, you might be able to get it back using

`git log` to find the sha1, and reset to it using

`git reset --hard <commit sha1>`

Remember that --hard will discard any changes not stashed and move the HEAD to this commit, so make sure you properly stash anything you need to save.

Comment: What about `git stash list`?